# Hosting a PHP application on Kubernetes (Google Container Engine)

Tags: apache-2.2, php, mongodb, google-cloud-platform, kubernetes

I need to host a PHP application on the Kubernetes infrastructure of Google Cloud Container Engine but I do not know how to procees, where to begin etc.

Basically the app was running on a VM with Apache and MongoDB. How can we make the same infrastructure but designed for Kubernetes and how to install it on GKE?

Comment: You need to create your images, then add them to a pod or deployment in Kubernetes. Here's a brief how to including automating deployments with Github, and Travis CI: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/automating-docker-container-deployment-github-travis-ci-mike-sparr/

Answer (score 1):

I hope you're not talking about building a kubernetes based architecture.  If you're asking the question in these terms, then it's a long road ahead, and almost certainly not something you'll get done this year or next.

If you are looking to move your app to a kubernetes cluster someone else runs, then kubernetes is mostly the concern of that someone else, and your problem at this point is containerisation of your app.

You might be best to focus first on getting your app containerised and running using docker and docker-compose, and then look at replacing the docker-compose bit with an equivalent kubernetes recipe.

You might also want to be very clear about why you want to move to kubernetes.  How much scaling do you really need?